# Applying savitzky golay filter to MODIS NDVI data

Tags: remote-sensing, modis, filter, envi, ndvi

I want to smooth the NDVI MODIS 16 bit integer data .tif for LULC classification. I have timesat 3.1 software on windows but I don't how to apply the SG filter. I am not that good in programming. I tried opening .tif(40mb) in timesat  but the data is not loaded. Should I have to convert the .tif images to some other format? Can I achieve my aim using ENVI?

Comment: Looks like Matlab has a function for this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sgolayfilt.html?refresh=true

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert all the images to a compatible format. Timesat needs to work headless binary images. ENVI format could be one of them.

After that you can use the imageview and GUI interface to apply one filtter and save to a settings file to run TSF or TSM process